# Oracle sqldeveloper trigger successfully compiled; invalid error - what is wrong with my syntax?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am stumped on why my trigger I have created in sqldeveloper, oracle, is successfully compiled:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER revoke_privileges_trigger
BEFORE DELETE ON department
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE DELETE ON department FROM User1';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE DELETE ON department FROM User2';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE DELETE ON department FROM User3';
END;


Trigger REVOKE_PRIVILEGES_TRIGGER compiled
```

but when I test it with this:
delete from DEPARTMENT where DEP_NAME = 'Data Analytics';

by trying to delete I get this error code:

Error starting at line : 51 in command -
delete from DEPARTMENT where DEP_NAME = 'Data Analytics'
Error at Command Line : 51 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.BEFORE_DELETE_USER1' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

What I want is to revoke privileges for any user, however I am working on this for school so not sure if it is because I am the "system" or what.

Can anyone help? I'm spinning wheels.

I did not expect to get an error code but rather an output with updated privileges when I tested the trigger with this syntax: delete from DEPARTMENT where DEP_NAME = 'Data Analytics';

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic SQL isn't evaluated for correctness when the trigger is compiled. DDL statements like you included generate an implicit commit, which is illegal in the context of the trigger. In general, DDL should not be embedded in application code. A trigger can evaluate a user's privileges and raise an error if the evaluation fails, but should not actually change any privileges assigned to the user.